# Configuring MemCachier with django+celery, do I input username and password?

Tags: django, memcached, celery

Celery configuration includes support for memcached with the `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`. The example from [the documentation](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#conf-cache-result-backend) is:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'cache+memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'
```

I'm currently trying to configure celery to use memcahed with my [MemCachier](https://www.memcachier.com/) cache, so I have it configured like this:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'cache+memcached://mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211'
```

where `mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211` is the url:port of my cache.

The problem is that now when celery attempts to use the cache to store results, I get an `invalid username or password` error:

```
12:04:29 worker.1 | ClientError: error 9 from memcached_set: (0x2f2a520) invalid username or password,  host: mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211
```

I can't find any example of a celery backend configuration which includes a username and password for memcached, but I attempted to format it like this:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'cache+memcached://<user>:<password>@mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com:11211'
```

and ended up with this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<password>@mc5.dev.ec2.memcachier.com'
```

which seems to indicate that the url wasn't parsed correctly. Does anybody know the correct way to configure celery to use MemCachier with the username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. The trick isn't to create a new reference to the cache through the `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND` which would require authentication, but instead to use a reference to your (already authenticated) django cache backend.

In other words, once you have this working:

```
In [1]: from django.core.cache import cache

In [2]: cache.set('foo', 'bar')
Out[2]: True

In [3]: cache.get('foo')
Out[3]: 'bar'
```

the celery backend can be configured to use the cache like this:

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend'
```

Answer (score 0):

First off the celery cache backend will use with the `pylibmc` or `memcache` module, depending on what's available. You need to ensure that you use `pylibmc` because that's what MemCachier supports.

Secondly it seems that MemCachier doesn't document the authentication scheme. You should probably read the source of pylibmc to see how it handles this.

I would think that you will have to sublcass `celery.backends.cache.CacheBackend` to add auth support.